# Wso2 moving files in (sftp) folder without processing them

Tags: wso2, sftp, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

We have a situation where we're trying to process around 200 files by picking them up from an sftp '**in**' folder, processing them, and then moving them to another '**out**' folder after the processing is completed.

However the files are being moved by wso2 directly to the '**out**' folder without being processed. This happens even though it's processing all the files one by one and not all at a time. We even tried adding a file process interval between each file, but still the issue remains.

For our setup in prod we have deployed our car using 2 pods in Kubernetes (we even tried with a single pod to no avail).

Note: This issue happens when the files are put in smb and local folder as well.

Why is this happening?

Edit: Here are the parameters we're defining in the proxy for moving the files:

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.PollInterval">10</parameter>      
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileProcessInterval">5000</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file://D:/integration_name/in</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file://D:/integration_name/error</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.xml</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file://D:/integration_name/out</parameter>
```

Comment: Normally where a question is duplicated deliberately here, we close the second one in favour of the first one. However since this has had no activity, I will vote to close this one instead. Please do not duplicate your questions.

Comment: This post is a duplicate of another question from the OP: [WSO2 moving files in sftp without processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76762488/wso2-moving-files-in-sftp-without-processing)